# MySQL error in OpenStack database keystone

Tags: mysql, openstack

I just noted that when i query the database named keystone in MySQL installed with test Open-Stack setup , the following:

```
 `MariaDB [keystone]> describe group;
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the    manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right  syntax to use near ''group'' at line 1
  MariaDB [keystone]> describe keystone.group;
  +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
  +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  | id          | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
  | domain_id   | varchar(64) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
  | name        | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
  | description | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  | extra       | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
  +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
  5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  MariaDB [keystone]> describe user;
 +--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------       +
 | Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra        |
 +--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------     +
 | id                 | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |         |
 | name               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 | extra              | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | password           | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | enabled            | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 | domain_id          | varchar(64)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
 | default_project_id | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 +--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
 7 rows in set (0.00 sec)`
```

so the describe command works with any table except the `group` table, which has to be qualified with db name. It is a bug or just because the group is a keyword also?

Thanks

Comment: think it you should use backtick not quote around your table name

Comment: ohh that was a typo in writing the question , infact i tried all options like `group` , `'group'` , `(group )` etc , question updated

Comment: backticks are not single quotes. They are used to escape reserved words. This is a single quote ' and this is a backtick `

Comment: with table name `group` only back quotes work (the one you use to mark code here) no other options will work

Comment: Ohhh yes , it worked , but why is it not working without back quotes like other table names?

Comment: Because it is a reserved word in SQL, and the parser expects other tokens to follow that turn it into a legal expression, but they don't.